# How do I get sphinx-build to throw errors when a file is not found or a directive is misconfigured?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I am stuck on sphinx-build 6.2.1 because of the rtd theme: https://github.com/readthedocs/sphinx_rtd_theme/issues/1463

This works because the file exists and the config is right:

```
.. literalinclude :: ../../this/file/exists.json
   :language: json
```

The follow snippets do *not* render the JSON file and throw zero errors even when running: `sphinx-build -vvv -b html mydocs docscompiled`

```
.. literalinclude :: ../../this/file/DOES_NOT_EXIST.json
   :language: json

.. literalincludezzzzz :: ../../this/file/DOES_NOT_EXIST.json
   :language: jsonzzzz
```

It's impossible to know what the problem is. File path wrong or directive misconfigured.

Is this maybe something fixed in 7.x?

## Edit

For reference below is my entire `conf.py`:

```
import os
import sys
import importlib.metadata

__version__ = importlib.metadata.version("myproject")
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(".."))
project = "myproject"

version = __version__
release = __version__

extensions = [
    "sphinx.ext.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.autosummary",
    "sphinx.ext.napoleon",
    # _typehints and _defaultargs always come after napoleon
    "sphinx_autodoc_typehints",
    "sphinx_autodoc_defaultargs",
    "invocations.autodoc",
    "sphinx.ext.doctest",
    "sphinx.ext.intersphinx",
    "sphinx.ext.todo",
    "sphinx.ext.coverage",
    "sphinx.ext.mathjax",
    "sphinx.ext.ifconfig",
    "sphinx.ext.viewcode",
]

napoleon_use_param = True
autodoc_default_options = {
    "members": True,
    "undoc-members": True,
    "private-members": True,
}
autosummary_generate = True

# For sphinx_autodoc_defaultargs
rst_prolog = (
    """
.. |default| raw:: html

    <div class="default-value-section">"""
    + ' <span class="default-value-label">Default:</span>'
)

templates_path = ["_templates"]
language = "en"
exclude_patterns = ["_build", "Thumbs.db", ".DS_Store"]
pygments_style = "sphinx"
html_theme = "sphinx_rtd_theme"
todo_include_todos = True
```

Comment: With the first bad sample, I get `WARNING: Include file 'c:\\my\\path\\this\\file\\DOES_NOT_EXIST.json' not found or reading it failed`. With the second, I get `ERROR: Unknown directive type "literalincludezzzzz`

Comment: @mzjn what version are you on?

Comment: I tested this with Sphinx 6.1.3. You could try to run the command without `-vvv`. The errors can be easy to miss when there also is a barrage of log messages.

Comment: I did it without the verbose switches first which is why I switched to using them. Is there anything in my config that could cause the swallowing of these errors?

Comment: I have no idea, sorry.

Comment: I've likely messed this project up or one of my plugins is causing issues. At least I can confirm now its only my project and not native sphinx behavior.

Comment: Maybe [_`nitpicky`_](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-nitpicky) or [`sphinx-build -n`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-n) on command line combined with [`-W`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-W).